# Автоматизация GUI. Выбор элемента меню в приложении на .net

Tags: python, pywinauto

Доброго времени суток. Осваиваю python и библиотеку для автоматизации pywinauto.
Пробую автоматизировать действия в одном приложении, использующем WPF.

[image: Скриншот меню]

Проблема в том, что не удается выбрать дочерние подпункты меню.
Собственно код:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from os import getenv

skif_path = getenv('localappdata') + '\ОАО Финтех\СКИФ-Бюджетный процесс\SkifBP.exe' + ' /SERVER=(localdb)\Fintech /DATABASE=Skif_BP /AUTOLOGON /SSPI=1'
app = Application(backend='uia').start(r''+skif_path)

main_window = app.window(title='СКИФ-Бюджетный процесс')
main_window.wait('ready', timeout=25)

top_menu = main_window.child_window(auto_id="TopMenu")
menu_service = top_menu.child_window(title="Сервис", control_type="MenuItem")
#menu_service.select() - срабатывает нормально
item_backup = menu_service.child_window(title="Резервное копирование...", control_type="MenuItem")
item_backup.select()
```

"Верхние" пункты отлично выбираются, но при попытке обращения к дочернему (например "Резервное копирование...") получаю ошибку, что не удается найти нужный элемент:

> pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Резервное
>   копирование...', 'control_type': 'MenuItem', 'top_level_only': False,
>   'parent': ,
>   'backend': 'uia'}

**print_control_identifiers** [выдает](https://pastebin.com/wWRzs7x5) корректное дерево элементов (описания элементов я и копировал из вывода)

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему.

Comment: многоточие в меню как ascii записано или U+2026?

Comment: @jfs, как ascii, но дело не в этом. Та же проблема с дочерними элементами без многоточия в наименовании. Забыл упомянуть что menu_select вообще не видит это меню.

Comment: можно конечно в качестве временного решения эмулировать выбор с клавиатуры menu_service.type_keys('{DOWN 2}{ENTER}')

Comment: Добрый день, скорее всего проблема в том, что выпадающее меню не отрисованно, так как у его элементов "нулевые" rectangle'ы, попробуйте сперва выбрать нужный пункт, так же желательно для наглядности после каждого выбора выводить дерево дочерних элементов для проверки

Comment: @Boris извиняюсь, что не ответил, не было возможности.
Пробовал выбрать нужный пункт, а потом уже выбрать в нем нужный элемент, но тоже не срабатывало. Если после выбора пункта меню, вывести дерево элементов окна, то получается, что после раскрытия пункта меню, создается новое меню с именем вида СервисDropDown, но у него нет дочерних элементов: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26446627/

Comment: Но элементы вижу отрисовались, возможно child_window не находит их потому что родитель определен неправильно, попробуйте все таки использовать wrapper'ы скорее всего это будет http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.menuwrapper.html и вместо select можно попробовать click